# How to dynamically require JSON files in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, webpack, webpack-4

I have a bunch of json files that I need to dynamically `require`:

```js
export const allLanguages = R.fromPairs(availableLanguages.map(language => {
  return [
    language,
    {
      translation: require('./' + language + '.json'),
      formats
    }
  ] as [Language, any]
}))
```

But I get `Error: Cannot find module './ar.json'` when running `webpack --watch`, and I can see that the json files have not been copied to the build directory.

So I tried adding `{from: 'common/i18n/*.json'}` to CopyWebpackPlugin arguments, and now the json files are copied to the correct place, but I still get `Error: Cannot find module './ar.json'` when running `webpack --watch`. It seems they are copied after the build, not before it, and hence the error.

There seems to be feature request for allowing copying files before the build for CopyWebpackPlugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/issues/195

What is the correct way to handle this in Webpack?

Comment: In my opinion this problem should not be solved inside webpack's context. You need some json files to be present in a specific directory before running the build command. Why not copying them using nodejs fs module before exporting your `webpack.config.js`?